# load long files into memory - Android

Tags: android, memory-management, out-of-memory

I'd like to load a file of 30-40 MB into memory, and the process it. But the problem is I get an Out of Memory error.

I set `android:largeHeap="true"` in Android Manifest but the problem is not solved. What's the best solution?

I've heard is possible execute android app that use more than 100Mb of Ram. But I don't know how to do that.

Thanks in advance

Regards

Comment: a/ post your file loading process. possibly you are duplicating it, or putting it into a string (which doubles the memory occupation) ... b/ why on earth would you consider loading a 30MB file in memory ?

Comment: The best solution is not to load the whole file at once.

Comment: the file contais a double[][][] which I need for visualizing 3D images

Answer (score 0):

I never handled for 3D images. I mean I am not sure which kind of performance you expected ?
But you have to scaled based on your design. E.g. It's not worth to load big resolution, 1280x1280 to show as 100x100 thumbnail image.

This tutorial is worth to read http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html.

I recommend to follow the whole branch of Bitmap handling. I hope this answer will help you.